# Creating Themes in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, themes

I know in Windows XP it was not a trivial exercise to create your own themes.  Is this task easier in Windows 7?  And if so, what is involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft made creating and sharing themes really simple, thanks to a new file format `.themepack`, which is basically a special ZIP format that includes cursors, sounds, wallpapers, icons, colors and more.

Read [this article](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-a-theme-pack-in-windows-7-detailed-guide/) for an illustrated step-by-step guide to creating themes on Windows 7.

Comment: I vote down. It's not ZIP.

Answer (score 4):

If you actually meant hacking [.msstyle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSSTYLES) files, it's just as hard in Windows 7.

I think you will need to open the aero.msstyle file up using [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) and modify the files in Photoshop.  Or you could modify a custom theme that somebody else has made.  You can find them, and other people who have done this, on [Deviantart](http://win7themedesigners.deviantart.com/#).

[image: Hacked Windows 7 .msstyle theme]

Personally, I don't think many amateur themes are ever going to look as good as the default Aero styles, although there may be some good ones that are just slightly altered.